# How to run a cron command every hour taking script execution time in account?

Tags: database, cron

I have a bunch of data to monitor. My data are statistics that can only be retrieved every hour but can change every second and I want to store into a database as much values as I can for each data set.

I've though about several approaches for this problem and I finally chose to refresh and read all statistics at once instead of reading them independently.

So that, I came out with command `mycommand` which reads all my statics with the cost of several minutes (let's say 30) of execution. Now I would like to run this script every hour, but taking the script execution into account.

I actually run

```
* */1 * * * mycommand.sh
```

and receive many annoying error emails (actually one every hour) and I effectly retrieve my statistics every 2 hours.

Comment: Read *carefully* [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)

Comment: You could have it run every 30 minutes and at the top of the script check what time it is and have it run a set of commands only for a specified number of times. Supervisor might be an option too.

Comment: BTW, what is the use case? Why can't you run that job every hour, or every two hours? Consider editing your question to motivate it

Comment: Question rewritten, don't know if I had to re-add it

Answer (score 0):

1h 30 minutes is the half of 3 hours. So you could have two entries in  [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) running the same `/home/gogaz/mycommand.sh` script, one to run it at 1, 4, 7, ... hours (every 3 hours from 1am) and another to run  it at 2:30, 5:30, 8:30 hours, ... (every 3 hours from 2:30am) etc

Writing these entries is left as an exercise to the reader.

See also [anacrontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/anacrontab.5.html) and [at(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at). For example, you might run your script once using `batch`, but terminate your script with an `at` command rescheduling that same script (the drawback is handling of unexpected errors).

If you redirect your stdout and stderr in your crontab entry, you won't get any emails.